# Suddenly no audio on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have been on Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.13.0-67 generic for a long time now, but suddenly lost my audio a few weeks back - both internal speakers and earphones. I am using an Asus Zenbook UX330UA dual booted with Windows 10 (audio used to work occasionally on Windows, no works on neither OS). The output of `aplay -l` does detect the inbuilt sound card

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]        

Subdevices: 1/1

 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]

Subdevices: 1/1

Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]

Subdevices: 1/1

 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]

 Subdevices: 1/1

Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]

Subdevices: 1/1

Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I tried using the troubleshooting guide on Launchpad, but to no success. The logs of the troubleshooting can be found [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+question/665637). The audio starts working abruptly after a reboot sometimes, but that is occasional. Reinstalling Realtek drivers on Windows 10 helped a couple of times, but that doesn't work now either. `pavucontrol` and `alsa-mixer` wasn't too helpful either.

Comment: Update: There was an issue with the hardware audio driver, which is why it wasn't being recognized. The audio works fine now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am on kernel 4.13.0-36 generic, and it's after the latest updates done. I do not know how you have a -67 version. Can't even find it on google.

Have you tried the newest 16.04 LiveCD to see if the card works to begin with?

Also, some installs, such as Teamviewer, or Skype, may change your .conf files. Have you looked at them?

*/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf*
and the files in */etc/pulse/*

And in alsamixer, F5 to show all, none of the channels/options show MM (which stands for Muted), right? Except maybe the Headphone option.